# Druid ingestion across multiple Druid environments/clusters

Tags: druid

Is there a simplified way to ingest raw data into one Druid environment then use the result from Druid stored in Druid Deep Storage to re-ingest the result into a diff Druid environment(different Druid cluster) or simply ingest from one druid cluster to another Druid cluster?

FROM: Raw Data --> data pipeline/Airflow --> Druid (environment 1)
TO: Raw Data --> Airflow --> Druid (environment 1) --> Druid (environment 2)

Looking to achieve this due to the time it takes to ingest raw data into druid. Instead of Ingesting raw data for each environment, I would like to ingest raw data once and copy result into another Druid environment.

Deep storage is using S3, so I can copy data from S3 (environment 1) to S3(environment 2). However, metadata needs to be updated as well, but this looks a hacky way to achieve it.

Looking also for best practices for this scenario if I want to avoid duplicating data pipelines for each Druid environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. If you have the metadata stored in for example mysql, you can just copy this data and insert these records in your second environment.

All segment data is stored in MySQL as data-store. This sounds complicated, but it is not. Just take a look in the
`druid_segments` table and filter on your dataSource.

Just copy over the records which you want to "move". Just make sure that the location (path) of the deep storage file is accessible from your second environment. Possible, you can alter these paths in the "payload" field if needed.

See also this page with some useful tips:

https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/115004960053-Migrate-existing-Druid-Cluster-to-a-new-Imply-cluster